# why is $(-64)^{2/3} =-16$ and not $16$?

Tags: exponentiation

It appears that taking the cube root of a negative number will yield a negative number, which when squared, will yield a positive number.  But all the calculators and books I have seen show this particular problem yields a negative number.  Any help here?

Comment: Are you sure you're putting parentheses around the $-64$? If you enter it as $\displaystyle -64^{\frac{2}{3}}$ the calculator might interpret it as $\displaystyle -\left(64^{\frac{2}{3}}\right) = -16$.

Comment: Not just "might": it _will_. (Exponents and roots are done first, then the sign is appended.)

Comment: The calculator in Windows gives 16 as the result (when calculating $(-64)^{2/3}$).

Comment: I think if you enter $-64$ and then something like Ans^(2/3) it would actually interpret it as $\displaystyle (-64)^{\frac{2}{3}}$. I know it does on a TI-83 or 84. So, it might, depending on how he entered it.

Comment: I just pulled out four calculators of mine and tried it.  Three gave -16 and the fourth one choked.  I agree with **2012ssohn**'s interpretation: if you enter the problem directly, the "hierarchy of operations" will more likely than not give you -16, but using the "Ans" feature essentially "wraps parentheses" around the " -64" and then you can perform the powers-calculation correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed
$$
(-64)^{2/3} = 16.
$$
This can be seen two ways:
$$\begin{align}
(-64)^{2/3} &= ((-64)^{1/3})^2 = (-4)^2 = 16 \\
(-64)^{2/3} &= ((-64)^2)^{1/3} =(4096)^{1/3} = 16.
\end{align}
$$
Here remember that 
$$
a^{1/3} = \sqrt[3]{a}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Well let's take this step by step though you do seem to have an understanding of it.

The cube root of -64 is -4. So yes It does yield a negative number. Then the square of that is 16, so like the previous person said perhaps you have not entered it into the calculator properly.

Ah technology, a blessing but yet a curse.

Comment: This just illustrates a maxim going back to early electronic-computing days:  you should know what the machine does in performing the calculation before asking it to do it for you...